# Why does the finally stanza of a try..catch..finally block get run before catch?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

```js
try {
  throw new Error('yikes!');
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
} finally {
  console.log('caught error!')
}
```

Prints out:

```
caught error!
Error: yikes!
```

So is the `finally` block running *before* the throw statement?

It only *looks* like the finally block ran first, but we can see this isn't actually the case:

```js
let failed;

try {
  throw new Error('yikes!');
  failed = false;
} catch (e) {
  failed = true;
  throw e;
} finally {
  console.log(`caught error! failed: ${failed}`)
}
```

prints

```
caught error! failed: true
Error: yikes!
```

So why is the printing of the error out of band? is there some asynchronous behaviour here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's *not* running before the `catch`, hence `failed` is `true` (*post-edit*: hence `foo` is logged first). You seem to have answered your own question with that experiment; what part of this behaviour is still unclear?

Comment: You should really run `try { throw; } catch(e) { console.log("caught"); } finally { console.log("final"); }` to see in what order the blocks run. (And if you don't rethrow the exception, it doesn't get printed in the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try runs - Your try runs and throws the error
2. Catch runs - Your catch catches the error and simply re-throws it.
3. Finally runs - You print out your string
4. The rethrown error is now uncaught - And your browser logs details about the error

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` clause runs before the overall `try` block finishes. The error that's logged happens when the runtime intercepts the exception, which is *after* the `try` block finishes. (Note that your `catch` code does not `console.log()` anything. It throws a new exception, but the `finally` clause will still run before the rest of the world sees that.)

All languages with `try catch finally` that I know of behave in exactly the same way. The point of `finally` blocks is to provide a place to put code that is *guaranteed* to run whether the `try` succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0):

The `throw` statement doesn't print anything. The error is printed later when the browser catches the thrown error.